# Command failed: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, gulp, homestead, gulp-notify

I'm trying to run gulp and im getting the error:

```
gulp-notify: [Error in notifier] Error in plugin 'gulp-notify'
Command failed: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on a fix?

Im on OSX.

Comment: I'm assuming gulp is being run on your macintosh? If you're running it within Homestead, notifier won't work in any case, but also ruby might just not be installed.

Comment: You need to install ruby. Assuming you are using `brew`, the command should be `brew install ruby`.